# RTF document builder

Tags: c#, .net, rtf

I'm creating a program for new hires where I type in their name and some other info and it spits out a  welcome/new employee info document.

I seem to remember there was something along the lines of there being a document object that I could use (similar i guess to `StringBuilder`).

Is there such a thing already included in the .NET Framework 2 or 3?

Comment: You realise that RTF doesn't appear anywhere in your question title or text? Are you trying to ask whether there is a built-in writer for RTF files in .Net? Would any other document format do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're just using a text file, you can just use the StringWriter class in the System.IO Namespace.

(One of the constructors of a StringWriter object is StringBuilder)

Comment: Im trying to write a RTF file but string builder wasn't exactly what i wanted. I want to be able to control diffrent fonts sizes and things like bold and italics

Comment: I've done something similar: I just ended up using an invisible RichTextBox, in which all the formatting and text processing was done. Then just use the SaveFile() method or get the RTF from RichTextBox.RTF.